# Using Mac Automator to run a Knime Workflow

Tags: macos, automation, knime

I couldn't find a solution to automate a Knime workflow with MacOS. What kind of options does it have out there?

I've tried using Mac Automator, but it didn't worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot give any specific recommendations or first-hands experience about Apple Automator. You *should* be able to schedule a KNIME workflow using Automator and the KNIME CLI batch mode -- you can try this in a regular Terminal window first, and then transfer it to an Automator workflow with a “Execute Shell Script” action.

General documentation about the KNIME batch mode is available [here](https://www.knime.com/faq#q12).

Beside that, there’s a couple of further options:

- KNIME’s commercial “Hub” or “Server” product
- [Canopys](https://dev3lop.com/canopys-task-scheduler-2/) Task Scheduler
- [NodePit Runner](https://nodepit.com/product/runner) which is available as SaaS and on-prem hosted solution and currently available in a closed beta

Here’s a [thread](https://forum.knime.com/t/automatically-starting-workflow-that-writes-files-to-a-sharepoint-folder/55113) in the KNIME forum which is worth a read.